# High accuracy on both training and validation but very low on test set

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

My CNN model has about 96~97% accuracy on both training and validation sets. But when submitting the test set it got only 24% accuracy.
Here's my model:

```py
def build_cnn_model():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D())
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D())
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D())
    classifier.add(Flatten())
    classifier.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
    classifier.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return classifier
```

The training set has about 40k images, valid set has about 10k images and test set is made of 5.5k images. Here's my implementation

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'datasets/training_set',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=42,
    class_mode='categorical')

valid_set = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'datasets/valid_set/',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=42,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'original_data/',
    classes=['test'],
    target_size=(64, 64),
    seed=42,
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=1)

test_set.reset()

classifier = build_cnn_model()

classifier.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=1222,
    validation_data=valid_set,
    validation_steps=305)
```

Here we can see the behavior of the model [image: acc_loss_image] during training and I noticed that validation accuracy is always higher than training accuracy. So why this is happening? Why so low accuracy on test set and why validation accuracy is higher than training accuracy? What are the possible solutions?

Comment: wide guess is that you overfit the validation set. Your model can't generalize well

Comment: what is the size of your validation accuracy ? Maybe you could try with a smaller learning rate.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton my validation set has about 10k samples

Comment: @IsmailChafai what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: It is possible that the train and test set are biased to a particular type of data, which doesn't appear in the test set. Please try to use regularization

Answer (score 3):

You may be doing something funky with the labels on the test set that isn't happening to the train/validation.

Why are you passing `classes=["test"]` to the test datagen but not the others?

From [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/): "classes: Optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. ['dogs', 'cats']). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute class_indices."

Does the 'original_data/' have the same folder structure that 'datasets/training_set' and 'datasets/valid_set/' have?

Comment: No, the problem is that the 'original_data/' folder has only one folder called 'test'. Inside this folder I have a bunch of unlabel images. In short, I dont have a folder structure that allow me to work in the same way

Comment: @flpn Can you add the code to your question where you evaluate the test performance?

Comment: Another problem is that I don't have the code for test evaluation. It's a challenge that I submitted, I just got the acc on test set. But I could check manually the results and I saw that the accuracy was low

Comment: How about the code where you generate the submission? How are they controlling the order of the examples?